# problem regarding maximum modulus principle in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

$p(z)= z^n+ a_{n-1}z^{n-1} +a_{n-2}z^{n-2} +...+a_0$, where $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},...,a_0$ are all complex numbers. $|p(z)| \leq$1 for all z with |z|$\leq$1. $q(z)= 1+ a_{n-1}z +a_{n-2}z^{2} +...+a_0 z^n$ . Then -

1. |q(z)| $\leq$ 1 for all z with |z|$\leq$1
2. q(z) is constant polynomial
3. p(z)=$z^n$ for all complex number z
4. p(z) is constant polynomial

The answers are given to be 1,2,3. But if I take $a_0$ in such a way that $|a_0| \leq 1$ and $a_i$=0 for all i = 1(1)n-1 then p(z) is a constant polynomial satisfying the given properties. Thus option 3 can be discarded. When p(z) is constant, q(z) is non constant. Thus option 2 can be discarded as well. Again p(z)=$z^n$ also satisfies the given properties. Hence option 4 is discarded. Thus according to me the only correct option is option 1.

Again if option 1 is correct then by using maximum modulus principle on q(z) (as q(0)=1) we get q(z) is constant.

Please point it out where I am making the mistake.

Comment: I agree with you completely. I think then given answer is wrong.

Comment: $p$ cannot be constant since it starts with $z^n$

Comment: Oh yes. I absolutely missed that coefficient of $z^n$ is 1. Thank you @Conard . Please give me some hint on how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Write $q(z) = z^n\cdot p(1/z)$. What do you know about $\lvert q(z)\rvert$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$? What follows for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$? What can you say about $q(0)$? What then?